# Opposite to imagemagick montage

Tags: imagemagick

I printed a lot of composed images with `imagemagick` `montage` tool. I scanned them back and now I want to recover individual images. Due to the amount of images, I want to do it automatically, so I need the opposite operation of montage (plus some clever spiting due to scanner positioning errors).

Is this tool available?

Comment: You need Fred's (@fmw42) `multicrop`. He'll tell you all about and licensing etc... http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Or also multicrop2. See all my scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Comment: I assume the images aren't the same size, so you can't use `convert filename  -crop 1024x768 +repage +adjoin image_%02d.png` or similar